# How to use phonegap plugins in our android project

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to use sms plugin in my android application on phonegap

I've downloaded the required plugin
also, I've changed all the instances of "phonegap" to "cordova"
but I still get the error

```
    E/Web Console(2086): TypeError: Result of expression 
'window.plugins' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/pluginexample.html:38
```

please give me link to any working project that uses plugin(any) so that I can know where I am getting this error

thanks!!!

Comment: make sure that your plugin function call after onDevice ready function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var MyPlugin = function () {};

MyPlugin.prototype.mFunctionName = function (action , successCallback, failureCallback, arrVal) {    
    return PhoneGap.exec(successCallback, failureCallback,  "ClassName", 'maction',arrVal );
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("mObject", new MyPlugin());
});
```

your phonegap js will be in above form

you can call the above js like

```
window.plugins.mObject.mFunctionName('maction',function(success){},function(error){});
```

or

```
var mObj =  new MyPlugin();

    mObj.mFunctionName('maction',function(success){},function(error){});
```

Comment: make sure that your plugin function call after onDevice ready function

Comment: Can you tell me where to write plugin function calling code

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working sms plugin for phonegap. You can either use it as it is or rewrite for your specific needs!

[SMS Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSPlugin)

Comment: i've imported that project in my eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this [Add the PhoneGap Barcode Scanner Plugin to a Project, Write an App using Barcode Scanner Technology](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to use the plugin in your phonegap project or do you want to use phonegap plugin in your android (studio) project (If you are developing android apps with native langueage/java use android studio)?

The best way is from the plugin documentation. You can also check out this link : http://javatechig.com/cross-platform/phonegap/phonegap-sms-plugin-android